# What is the IC in this picture?

Tags: amplifier, digital-logic, integrated-circuit, identification

Can anyone help me identify this IC?

[image: Close-up of IC]

Context:

[image: IC in greater context]

Comment: Please describe the device that this IC is found within. Also consider posting an image showing additional components around the one in question for context. The logo is Analog Devices.

Comment: This IC is in circuit input analogue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like an [AD7740 Voltage-to-Frequency Converter](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad7740.pdf). The datasheet indicates that some of those parts have the "V0Y" branding seen in the picture.